# Compute the result of $\iiint_\Omega r^2 dv$

Tags: calculus

> Compute the result of $\iiint_\Omega r^2 dv$, where $\Omega$ is the right square pyramid with an $1\times1$ square bottom and a height of $h$, and $r$ is the distance between any point $P$ in the pyramid and the top vertex $O$.

And here is what I thought by placing the origin at the top of the pyramid (basically, it looks somthing like this):
[image]
$$\begin{split}\iiint_\Omega r^2 dv=\iiint_\Omega r^2 (r^2\sin\phi d\theta d\phi dr)
&=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{\arctan\frac{1}{2h}}\sin\phi d\phi\int_0^{\frac{h}{\cos\phi}}r^4dr\\
&=2\pi\int_0^{\arctan\frac{1}{2h}}\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{h}{\cos\phi}\right)^5\sin\phi d\phi\\
&\mathop{=}^{t=\cos\phi}-\frac{2\pi h^5}{5}\int_1^{\cos\arctan\frac{1}{2h}}t^{-5}dt\\
&=\frac{2\pi h^5}{5}\cdot\left.\frac{1}{4t^4}\right\vert^{\sqrt{\frac{4h^2}{4h^2+1}}}_1
\end{split}$$
which is obviously different from the correct answer $\frac{h}{30}(6h^2+1)$.

I'm wondering where went wrong in my answer, could someone point it out for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At a first glance, your spherical coordinates seem to integrate over a cone, not a pyramid.

Comment: Ok I have made a silly mistake, would it make sense if I change the triple integral to $4\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}d\theta\int_0^{\arctan\frac{1}{2h\cos\theta}}\sin\phi d\phi\int_0^{\frac{h}{\cos\phi}}r^4dr$?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot

Comment: To be honest, it looks like it's easier in Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states square bottom of $1 \times 1$ but your diagram shows $2 \times 2$ square.

As you rightly said in comments, the correct integral in spherical coordinates should be,

$ \displaystyle 8 \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\arctan (\sec\theta / (2h))} \int_0^{h \sec\phi} \rho^4 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

However note that the cross section of the pyramid parallel to xy-plane at any given $z$ is a square with $- \cfrac{z}{2h} \leq x, y \leq \cfrac{z}{2h}$.

So in cartesian coordinates, the integral can be written as,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{h} \int_{- z/(2h)}^{z/(2h)} \int_{- z/(2h)}^{z/(2h)} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \ dx \ dy \ dz$

Now using symmetry along x-axis and y-axis, you can rewrite it as

$\displaystyle 4 \int_0^{h} \int_0^{z/(2h)} \int_0^{z/(2h)} (2 y^2 + z^2) \ dx \ dy \ dz$

which is a simpler integral to evaluate than what you set up in spherical coordinates.

Comment: thanks, this approach does seem easier, and I've fixed the diagram problem

Comment: @babybobby you are welcome and good work with how you set up the vertex at the origin and applied spherical coordinates.